# send updated client list to all connected clients

Tags: vb6, winsock

Well, I have this code for my server connection request.

```
If sckClients(clientCounter).State <> adstateclosed Then sckClients(clientCounter).Close        
sckClients(clientCounter).Accept requestID
Command1.Enabled = True
MsgBox "Connected to client."
Combo1.AddItem sckClients(clientCounter).LocalIP & "(" & clientCounter & ")"
clientCounter = clientCounter + 1
Load sckClients(clientCounter)
```

And this is for updating the client list.

```
StrMsg = "1~Server~"
For x = 0 To Combo1.ListCount - 1
    If x = Combo1.ListCount - 1 Then
        StrMsg = StrMsg & Combo1.List(x)
    Else
        StrMsg = StrMsg & Combo1.List(x) & "~"
    End If
Next x


For x = 0 To clientCounter - 1
    sckClients(x).SendData StrMsg
Next x
```

My problem is, how can I send it to every client's combo box client list?

Comment: Since you *already are* sending it (as far as I can tell from the code you posted)... I assume you are asking an entirely different question.  Are you using the phrase "send to" to mean "display in" the ComboBox or something?

Comment: oh yes, that's what I meant. To display the client list to all connected client's combo box.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, (and based on Bob77's clarification) the message that you are sending to the connected clients could be something like this:

```
"1~Server~192.168.0.101(0)~69.125.83.76(1)~127.0.0.1(2)"
```

Then you would simply need to use the VB6's `split` function to get the information as such:

On Client (pseudo-code):

```
Private Sub WinSock_OnData(...)
    Dim Buffer As String
    Dim BufferArray() As String
    Dim Index As Long

    Call WinSock.GetData(Buffer, ...)        
    BufferArray = Split(Buffer, "~")

    If BufferArray(0) = "1" Then
        Call ComboxBox1.Clear        
        For Index = 1 To Ubound(BufferArray)
            Call ComboxBox1.AddItem(BufferArray(Index))
        Next Index
    End If

End Sub
```